# Solr : what is the syntax for "LIKE" on filters (fq)

Tags: apache, solr, search-engine

In my SOLR, i have indexed the keys (converted to string because the array wasn't saving) of the group which have the permission to display the object.

```
<visibility>
6-15-8
</visibility>
```

`'fq' => "current_status_i:".Ressource::STATUS_PUBLISHED ." + lang_t:".$culture. "+ visibility_s".$visibility`

**The problem** is that if the input for visibility is 15 it'll output 0 result because it does not match 6-15-8.

So , **what is the syntax to mimic the "LIKE" ** in order to have result if the input is 15, or 8....

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use multi-valued fields in Solr - they allow you to store multiple values for the same field. Check [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) and [this](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-are-multivalued-fields-used-td488853.html) for more details. Alternately, you can change the field type to ensure that the field is tokenized on `-` so that each value gets indexed separately.

Let me know how exactly you create the index and post your schema.xml.  I will then be able to give you some more details about adding multi-valued fields to your index.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options

1. Range query: fq=visibility:[1 To 15]
2. OR conditions: fq=visibility:6 OR 15 OR 8, (If you know these are the only 3 valid values in your system)

Comment: the problem is that i don't have only 1 record in my solr which contains visibility. I have 300 object with visibility range from 1 to 40. So i can't use the range query

Comment: and i can't use OR because sometimes i only have one variable to check (ex : 6) and 6 gives me 0 result.

Comment: @Tristan: I do not understand why you cannot use range query like [1 To 40]. It is not necessary the search result should always have something, right? If search does not show up anything, I guess its ok. Also you can make your query building dynamic to construct OR expressions based on the number of values given as input.